# Android: Building an APK almost doubles the size of an embedded video file?

Tags: android, video, apk, filesize

I have a video inside my APK that's about `9mb` in size. The APK file WITHOUT the video file is `14mb`. However, when I add the `9mb` video file, the apk size jumps to `30mb`.

The video is in `.mp4` format and I was wondering what was causing the APK to jump from `14mb` to `30mb` with a `9mb` video and is this normal? Thanks.

**Update:**
Turns out there are two res folders in my APK when using APK analyzer tool. They both have a copy of the video. Actually all my resources are being duplicated. This is the folder structure inside the APK:

```
res
main
   res
```

Comment: Use the APK analyzer tool from Android Studio to see what is taking space in your APK.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated my question. Turns out I have two res folders and they both have a copy of the video file

Comment: The video file should be in the res/raw folder - where did you put it?

Comment: Yea it's in the res/raw folder, but I dunno why it's copying all my resources from my main/res folder to the root res folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue that was duplicating every resource in my apk.

I had this block of code in my build.gradle file

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res'] // <-- This was causing the dup res folder
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets', 'src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
    }
}
```

I removed this block of code and now my apk is significantly smaller and no more duplications.